# How to grep ethernet interface, then pipe the information inside dialog command?

Tags: shell-script, grep

```
#!/bin/bash

enp=$(ls /sys/class/net | grep enp)
interface=$(dialog --stdout --menu "Select ethernet interface" 0 0 0 ${enp}) || exit 1
```

I want to auto detect the ethernet interface, then add this information in my Arch linux install script like so:

```
arch-chroot /mnt << EOF
systemctl enable dhcpcd@"$interface".service
EOF
```

But it isn't working. I also tried with | grep -Ev, but that gives me the wireless device.

[image]

Comment: You need run dialog with `--no-items` otherwise it expect 2 words per line.

Comment: Thank you! This has answered my question :) this really works.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to mark this as answered, but user meuh's answer solved my issue. I am very grateful!

```
#!/bin/bash

enp=$(ls /sys/class/net | grep -E enp)
interface=$(dialog --stdout --no-items --menu "Select ethernet interface" 0 0 0 ${enp}) || exit 1
```

Result:

[image]